# chromedriver-autoinstaller from behind a firewall

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way to use chromedriver-autoinstaller behind a firewall ?

Or is there any other better suited solution for maintaining the ChromeDriver when you are behind a firewall ?

Comment: This is not so much a technical question as it is a process and people question. You will need to work with your organization on this one. Something needs to allow traffic to download ChromeDriver. Maybe based on hostname and port?

Comment: I have the hostname and port (I use it when I need to pip install stuff).
I just don't know how this can be applied to update the Chromedriver automatically

Comment: Behind the firewall you cannot download anything, you have to contact your admin to exclude the URLs and filenames from the firewall.  My suggestion is instead of using chromedriver-autoinstaller use webdriver manager.

Comment: @AbiSaran: the OP will likely be blocked by the firewall, because web driver manager probably sends requests to the same URLs. Definitely reach out to IT admins on this one.

Comment: @AbiSaran
webdriver manager did the trick. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This is how I used  webdriver manager to solve my issue:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.core.download_manager import WDMDownloadManager
from webdriver_manager.core.http import HttpClient
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from requests import Response
import urllib3
import requests
import os
import time
os.environ['WDM_SSL_VERIFY'] = '0'
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

PROXY = "http:// *proxy adress*"
opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opt.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
opt.add_argument("ignore-certificate-errors")
opt.add_argument(f'user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\ *Location of the Chrome profile*')

class CustomHttpClient(HttpClient):
    def get(self, url, params=None) -> Response:
        proxies={'http': 'http:// *proxy adress*',
         'https': 'http:// *proxy adress*',
         }
        return requests.get(url, params,proxies=proxies,verify=False)

http_client = CustomHttpClient()
download_manager = WDMDownloadManager(http_client)


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager(download_manager=download_manager).install()),options=opt)
```

Comment: I just realised that this mess the automatic proxy setup.
Chrome triggered this way, can access to internet but not to intranet

Comment: On intranet sites that I try to open this way, I have now :"ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED"